# Make a div get to the top of another div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm making a template, and I'd like to have a div that his height gets to the top of another div. A screenshot that explains it a bit:
[image]

This is my CSS:

```
.grid_1 { width:60px; }
.grid_2 { width:140px; }
.grid_3 { width:220px; }
.grid_4 { width:300px; }
.grid_5 { width:380px; }
.grid_6 { width:460px; }
.grid_7 { width:540px; }
.grid_8 { width:620px; }
.grid_9 { width:700px; }

.column {
    margin: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.row {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row .row {
    margin: 0 -10px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_9"><p><img src="img/bomb.gif" style=" margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">
</p></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_3"><p style="line-height: 222px;">TEST</p></div>

    <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>
    <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>
    <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>



</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>
            <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>
            <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>

    </div>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/TmpBh/)

Comment: "I'd like to have a div that his height gets to the top of another div". What does this mean? Can you try to explain it a bit more and upload some pictures or somthing? Also, you should use the jsbin website if you want help with css and html to show what you have working.

Comment: I got images and some code, and jsbin doesn't allows CSS, I remember some page like that but I don't remember

Comment: @zad0xsis: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `float: left;` and `display: inline;` are contradicroy, IIRC.

Comment: @eric: http://jsfiddle.net/TmpBh/

Comment: @Eric, float + display inline is a fix for the float double margin bug of ie

Comment: zad0xis, which css framework is this? it seems you are missing some classes

Comment: Corroded: I made the first design with http://www.1kbgrid.com/ , I liked it and was doing a blog template

Comment: hmm looks like that grid is lacking some positioning stuff. create a class called .push_3 and put it as margin-left: 250px; add it to your post class and it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/TmpBh/3/ working stuff, but using iline-styles. just convert to a class

Comment: @zad0xsis: [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/TmpBh/2/)

Comment: i also suggest that you just use the 960-gs framework as this is similar to that and more

Comment: Thanks Eric, it works :D I made an answer with yours, if you want I'l delete it and you can out your own and I'll mark as correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was originally by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric):

[jsFiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/TmpBh/2/)

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/TmpBh/2/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_9">
        <img src="img/bomb.gif" style="margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_3"><p style="line-height: 222px;">TEST</p></div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden">
        <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>
        <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>
        <div class="column grid_6"><p>post</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>
    <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>
    <div class="column grid_3"><p>footer</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use .grid_6{float: right} and it should work.

Update:

A practice that I use is that I wrap such three divs in another div. I would do something like

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
 <div style="float: left">TEST</div>
 <div style="float: right; overflow: hidden">
  <div>POST</div>
  <div>POST</div>
  <div>POST</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same as the up answer, it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: i have updated my answer. However the first version should work as well. Are you sure, that the second rule is used? you can ensure that it is by adding float: right !important; instead of float: right;

Answer (score 0):

I guessed:

```
.grid_3 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to align the last post to the right, you can do a couple things

```
float:right; //may require parent to also float 
text-align:right; //to parent container
right:0px; // need to change position first I believe
margin-left:auto; // should push it to the right all the way
margin-left:123px; //fixed amount
```

Comment: where should I put that? I tried .grid_6, .grid_3, .column, .row and nothing